# How do I fix the "Sync out of range" error on start?

Tags: spec-ops-the-line

I just installed Spec Ops: The Line on Steam.  When I try to start it, I get a "Sync Out Of Range" error on my monitor.

**How do I fix this?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This error is caused by the game using a resolution that your monitor is incapable of displaying.

**To fix the Sync Out Of Range error in Spec Ops: The Line, follow these directions:**

1. Right click "Spec Ops: The Line" in your Steam library
2. Click Properties
3. Under the General tab pick "Set Launch Options"
4. Insert the following text into the box:

   > -windowed
5. Run the game
6. Adjust the resolution in the options screen to your monitor resolution
7. Quit the game
8. Remove the launch options
9. Restart the game

Answer (score 1):

Here is the fix for "Sync out of Range Error" in Spec Ops: The Line:

> Right Click on "SpecOpsTheLine.exe" and select "Properties" option.
>   The default path section will read as "C:\Program Files (x86)\2K
>   Games\Spec Ops The Line\Binaries\Win32"
>
> Target section in Properties window must read exactly this:
>   "C:\Program Files (x86)\2K Games\Spec Ops The
>   Line\Binaries\Win32\SpecOpsTheLine.exe"
>
> Now you need to add " -windowed" in target section without quotes
>   after "C:\Program Files (x86)\2K Games\Spec Ops The
>   Line\Binaries\Win32\SpecOpsTheLine.exe"
>
> After adding, the Target section will read something like this
>   "C:\Program Files (x86)\2K Games\Spec Ops The
>   Line\Binaries\Win32\SpecOpsTheLine.exe" –windowed."
>
> After completing and saving these changes, run Spec Ops: The Line and
>   change the resolution.
>
> Once done with changing resolution, remove " -windowed" from Target
>   section and save the changes once again..

Comment: Is this the fix for the non-steam version?